# Applescript - Duplicate Folder then rename & rename files inside

Tags: duplicates, applescript, rename

I'm trying to create a script that copies a template folder to current finder window then renames the new folder and a couple of files within it based on dialogue input.

So far, I've got it so it can copy a folder (from a selection) to the current finder window and rename it. But I can't get it to then rename a file within it.

Here's the code -

```
property A : POSIX file "/BLOCKED OUT FOR PRIVACY/" as alias
property B : POSIX file "/BLOCKED OUT FOR PRIVACY/" as alias
property C : POSIX file "/BLOCKED OUT FOR PRIVACY/" as alias
property D : POSIX file "/BLOCKED OUT FOR PRIVACY/" as alias

tell application "Finder"
set x to target of window 1 as alias
end tell

set JobName to text returned of (display dialog "Enter Folder Name:" default answer "Template Folder")

set CATno to text returned of (display dialog "Enter CAT number:" default answer "CMXX0000")

set optionList to {"OPTION 1", "OPTION 2", "OPTION 3", "OPTION 4"}

set chosenFolder to choose from list optionList with prompt "Choose a Folder"

set chosenFolder to chosenFolder's item 1

if chosenFolder is "OPTION 1" then

tell application "Finder"
    set FolderCopy to duplicate B to x
    set the name of FolderCopy to JobName
    set Insert to (POSIX path of (path to home folder)) & "DVD Insert Artwork/Indesign Project File/_Insert.indd" as POSIX file
    set the name of Insert to JobName & CATno
end tell
end if
```

I've cut out the POSIX file paths as they contain my company name and such. I've also left out the other parts of the if as they'll essentially be duplicates of the first.

```
set Insert to (POSIX path of (path to home folder)) & "DVD Insert Artwork/Indesign Project File/_Insert.indd" as POSIX file
set the name of Insert to JobName & CATno
```

This is the part that's giving me trouble. It should be renaming a file that is within the newly duplicated folder to the what's entered in the CATno dialog box + "_Insert.indd"

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure but do you mean this?

```
tell application "Finder"
    set FolderCopy to duplicate B to x
    set insertFile to file "_Insert.indd" of FolderCopy
    set the name of FolderCopy to JobName
    set name of insertFile to (JobName & CATno & "_Insert.indd")
end tell
```

The gets the reference to the indesign file from the duplicated folder.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However this returns an error - "Finder got an error: Can’t get file "_Insert.indd" of folder "Template Folder - HIDDEN" of folder "New" of folder "Downloads" of folder "Air.Giraffe" of folder "Users" of startup disk. (-1728)"                                                                                          The file I'm renaming is within a couple of subfolders of the duplicated folder, which might be the problem here?

Comment: You need to specify the full path to the file (colon separated) for example `set insertFile to file ((FolderCopy as text) &  "subfolder1:subfolder2:_Insert.indd")`. As your question does not contain any information about the folder hierarchy I can't be more accurate.

Comment: This worked! Thank you. I did have to move the  `set the name of FolderCopy to JobName` though.